# When I should use the MySqlCommand.EnableCaching property?

Tags: c#, mysql

What's doing `EnableCaching` property? I couldn't found any documentation about this property in the [official documentation](http://mysql-connector-net.sourcearchive.com/documentation/6.4.3-1/classMySql_1_1Data_1_1MySqlClient_1_1MySqlCommand.html).

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.EnableCaching = [true | false];
// other codes...
```

Any helpful source, comment, answer appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Use it as you see fit, but it requires extensive client and server-side tweaking to master desired results.

---

An excerpt from the Mysql Manual Page [Query Cache Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html):

> Setting the GLOBAL query_cache_type value determines query cache
>   behavior for all clients that connect after the change is made.
>   Individual clients can control cache behavior for their own connection
>   by setting the SESSION query_cache_type value. For example, a client
>   can disable use of the query cache for its own queries like this:
>
> `mysql> SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;`

Granted, the above is for for command line utilities, but it is not as if the Manual's presentation of the concept knows which connector (Java, .NET, etc) you are using. So that is the one it runs with. ***Your*** connector does a pass-thru of .NET's `command.EnableCaching` to the mysql connection's `query_cache_type`. That is on a connection-by-connection basis, and it dictates whether or not you want your results served by cache, assuming they are even cached. Which is wildly too broad issue to even bring up.

I am trying to keep this answer as narrow as possible. When should you use it? That is up to your application and you. And depending on whether or not your particular testing attempt is cached, it will vary on a case by case basis.

### Server-side

There are several things to look at, such as the size settings and whether or not caching is enabled. Also, whether the mysql daemon has adhoc runtime settings for cache sent to it and what survives with those settings on server restart. So it is not exactly an easy answer.

For that, I found a nice "*article two*" that supplements or surpasses the one from the reference above. The latter does give server information.

Article two is [Speed Up Your Web Site With MySQL Query Caching](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/). I include it in its entirety because after half an hour of searching, it seemed like the best information and I hope it does not vanish.

> One of the best ways to speed up your web application is to enable
>   query caching in your database, which caches commonly used SQL queries
>   in memory for virtually instant access by the next page that makes the
>   same request.
>
> The reason this method is so powerful is that you don’t have to make
>   any changes to your web application, you just have to sacrifice a
>   little bit of memory. This isn’t going to fix all of your problems,
>   but it definitely can’t hurt.
>
> Note: if your application updates tables frequently, then the query
>   cache will be constantly purged and you won’t get much or any benefit
>   from this. This is ideal for an application that mostly does reads
>   against the database, such as a WordPress blog. This also won’t work
>   if you are running on shared hosting.
>
> **Enable Caching with Server Running**
>
> The first thing you’ll want to do is make sure that your installation
>   of MySQL actually has query caching support available. Most
>   distributions do, but you should check anyway.
>
> You’ll want to run this command from your MySQL console, which will
>   tell you if query caching is available.
>
> ```
> mysql> show variables like 'have_query_cache';
> +------------------+-------+
> | Variable_name    | Value |
> +------------------+-------+
> | have_query_cache | YES   |
> +------------------+-------+
> ```
>
> Don’t mistake this as meaning that query caching is actually enabled,
>   because most hosting providers aren’t
>   going to enable this by default. Oddly enough, my Ubuntu Feisty
>   installation already had it enabled…
>
> Next we’ll need to check and see if query caching is enabled. We’ll
>   need to check more than one variable, so we may as well do it all at
>   once by checking for the variable `query%`
>
> ```
> mysql> show variables like 'query%';
> +------------------------------+---------+
> | Variable_name                | Value   |
> +------------------------------+---------+
> | query_alloc_block_size       | 8192    |
> | query_cache_limit            | 1048576 |
> | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096    |
> | query_cache_size             | 8388608 |
> | query_cache_type             | ON      |
> | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF     |
> | query_prealloc_size          | 8192    |
> +------------------------------+---------+
> ```
>
> Here’s the important items in the list and what they mean:
>
> **query_cache_size** – This is the size of the cache in bytes. Setting
>   this value to 0 will effectively disable caching.
>
> **query_cache_type** – This value must be ON or 1 for query caching to be enabled by default.
>
> **query_cache_limit** – This is the maximum size query (in bytes) that
>   will be cached.
>
> If the query_cache_size value is set to 0 or you just
>   want to change it, you’ll need to run the following command, keeping
>   in mind that the value is in bytes. For instance, if you wanted to
>   allocate 8MB to the cache we’d use 1024 * 1024 * 8 = 8388608 as the
>   value.
>
> ```
> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 8388608;
> ```
>
> Similarly, the other options can be set with the same syntax:
>
> ```
> SET GLOBAL query_cache_limit = 1048576; 
> SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
> ```
>
> Now how do we tell if it’s actually working? You can use the `SHOW STATUS` 
>   command to pull all the variables that start with “Qc” to take  a look
>   at what is going on under the hood.
>
> ```
> mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';
> +-------------------------+--------+
> | Variable_name           | Value  |
> +-------------------------+--------+
> | Qcache_free_blocks      | 65     | 
> | Qcache_free_memory      | 201440 | 
> | Qcache_hits             | 18868  | 
> | Qcache_inserts          | 2940   | 
> | Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 665    | 
> | Qcache_not_cached       | 246    | 
> | Qcache_queries_in_cache | 492    | 
> | Qcache_total_blocks     | 1430   | 
> +-------------------------+--------+
> 8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> You’ll notice in the stats that I have plenty of free memory left. If your
>   server shows a lot of lowmem prunes, you might need to consider
>   increasing this value, but I wouldn’t spend too much memory on query
>   caching for a web server… you need to leave memory available for
>   apache, php, ruby, or whatever you are using.
>
> **Enable in Config File**
>
> If you want these changes to survive a reboot or restart of the mysql
>   server, you’ll need to add them into your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
>   configuration file for MySQL. Note that it might be in a different
>   location on your installation.
>
> Open up the file using a text editor in sudo or root mode, and then
>   add these values if they don’t already exist in the file. If they do
>   exist, just uncomment them.
>
> ```
> query_cache_size = 268435456
> query_cache_type=1
> query_cache_limit=1048576
> ```
>
> Query caching can significantly improve the
>   speed of your web application, especially if your application does
>   mostly reads. Monitor the status using the methods above and see how
>   it works over time.